# Qt RemoteObjects

Tags: c++, qt

I try to send custom Object with Qt Remote Objects.

I declared my class like that:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>
#include <QDataStream>

class Model : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit Model(QObject *parent = nullptr);

  Model(const Model &other);

  ~Model();

  bool operator!=(Model &other);
  Model operator=(Model &other);

  QDataStream operator<<(const Model&);
  Model operator>>(const QDataStream);
signals:

public slots:

public:
  QString text1;
  QString text2;

};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Model)
```

My rep file looks like:

```
#include "../model/Model.h"

class Remote {
  PROP(Model resultModel);

  SLOT(void resultModelChanged_slot(Model resultModel));
};
```

When I try to build the application I get the following error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘QDataStream’ and ‘const Model’)
         stream << *static_cast<const T*>(t);
```

Does anyone know about some complex QtRemoteObject example? The example I have found is pretty simple and works (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtremoteobjects-gettingstarted.html) but I haven't found an example with complex (custom) types.

In the documentation about rpc I read that customTypes are supported (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtremoteobjects-repc.html)

Would be awesome if someone has an idea about that issue...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be declared in the global scope, outside of the class:

```
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &stream, const Model&);
```

Be careful with the returned value, the `operator <<` must return the same `stream` as it takes through the first argument, i.e. by a reference.

The class inside should declare a friend function:

```
friend QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &stream, const Model&);
```

Comment: This will fix the compile error, but doesn't actually work with the .rep file defined.  Qt doesn't support copying Qt QObjects, as the connect()s and ownership are basically undefined.  You can use the CLASS keyword in .rep to get around this (it creates an additional replica internally), but the documentation is behind for this feature.  An example is here: https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtremoteobjects.git/tree/tests/auto/subclassreplica/class.rep#n7